# How can I install a yii extension, making it available to my whole web application?

Tags: yii, yii-extensions

Recently I decided to study php and I discovered yii framework. At first glance it seemed very easy to work with it but now I am struggling to configure my web application for installing an extension to work with Enums. I downloaded this extension from their web site and I put it within extensions folder. The issue is that I am not able to call the subclasses that I created in my code. I created a few classes that extend from this superclass (extension).

Which configuration I must do to make this extension class, available to my web application code?

As I said I just put that extension class in my extensions folder and I am just instantiating them, inside controller's methods. When I run the code I see the same error message no matter any configuration I make:

**include (xxx.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**

If anyone does want to know more about this extension this is the page that shows some information about that.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/enum/

Answer (score 0):

in `config/main.php` you should add your extension details in the components array, something like:

```
    return array(
        // 'preload'=>array('xyz',...),
        'components'=>array(
            'xyz'=>array(
                'class'=>'ext.xyz.XyzClass',
                'property1'=>'value1',
                'property2'=>'value2',
            ),
            // other component configurations
        ),

);
```

where `xyz` is an extension

or just put it in the extensions folder and import it by `Yii::import('application.extensions.extensionname.*');`

Comment: You can also add it to global import in config `'import => ['alias.*']'` to avoid importing in each view.

Comment: I followed your instructions but then now I get a fatal error, saying that the abstract class Enum could not be instantiated. Is there an extra configuration that I need to do so I can solve now this error?

Comment: I even tried to put one line for the import section, so it could be available in my entire web application for use, but I still was with the same error:

**include (xxx.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory**. I still don't get it. Why the application is complaining about the instance of this extension class if it is an abstract class? If I did the right configuration, the application should not have been complaining about the issue of instantiation of the abstract class, because I created subclasses from it, so I thought it never would complain about this class.